# ubuntu 20.04, without GUI, change ctrl-alt-del to shutdown -h now

Tags: configuration

I have a question about using ubuntu desktop 20.04(GUI removed).

When I leave my virtual machine after daily work are done.

I want it shutdown, without `sudo shutdown -h now` and input that mighty password again.

Want it directly from the "Insert Ctrl+Alt+Del" feature in virtualbox menu.

It seems people on the Internet want only disable this feature or change it's behaviour from GUI.

I searched through some topics from google and found nothing but through these(haven't tried any) methods I described above,
and they are not the solution at all(at least that's how I feel).

Searching with "Debian" keyword end up the same

Anyone tried to do this before?